# How to set a WordPress custom post type visibility to private after editing?

Tags: wordpress, visibility, custom-post-type, private

I created a custom post type with a plugin. A registered user can insert a new post from front-end and it is saved as draft. When I edit it in back-end I need it is saved with private visibility.
I found this snippet to set visibility by default:

```
public function force_dpa_request_private( $data , $postarr ) {

    if( empty( $data['post_name'] ) && 'my-cpt' == $postarr['post_type'] )
        $data[ 'post_status' ] = 'private';

    return $data;

}
```

but it works only on first insert, when I edit it the visibility change to public...

Answer (score 0):

You can hook to the `save_post` which is called after the post is created or updated.

```
 <?php

    add_action( 'save_post', 'callback_save_post', 10, 3);
    function callback_save_post( $post_ID, $post, $update ){
        if ( 'my-cpt' === get_post_type( $post_ID) && ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_ID ) ) {
            // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
            remove_action('save_post', 'callback_save_post', 10 );

            // Make the post private if it is edited else make it draft.
            if ( $update ) {
                $postarr = array(
                    'ID' => $post_ID,
                    'post_status' => 'private'
                );
            } else {
                $postarr = array(
                    'ID' => $post_ID,
                    'post_status' => 'draft'
                );
            }

            // Update the post.
            wp_update_post( $postarr );

            // re-hook this function.
            add_action( 'save_post', 'callback_save_post', 10, 3);
        }
    }
```

Reference:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I think there is a syntax error on line 5 (remove_action accepts just three parameters) but however the system seems to stuck (very slow to save post) and after submit a get an incomplete page on front-end. On back-end I find the post but it continues to have private visibility not draft...

Comment: @icolumbro I fixed the code. Can you show us the error?

Comment: It goes in infinite loop because if I var_dump($update) after saving a post a get a full never ending bool(true) page... :(

Comment: @icolumbro Ok let me check it.

Comment: some news? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation from your question, but you can still edit the post on creation, if you make all your post type private.  Thus this works.

```
 function force_type_private($post)
  {
  if ($post['post_type'] == 'Your Post Type')
  $post['post_status'] = 'private';
  return $post;
  }
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'force_type_private');
```